# Removing lead white space - UNIX

Tags: unix

I've been working this problem for most of today as I'm a newbie.
Have looked at many examples but still get undesired output.
A snippet of what the file looks like this now -

File

[image]

And it needs to look like this.

Desired output

[image]

I started with deleting unnecessary files.
However, when I've tried to manipulate the column over to the right I get a screen full of numbers.

I've been working on getting rid of white space and I'm pretty sure I've tried everything on this site. :):
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To remove extra whitespaces from a file you may use the following simple approach with `sed` command:

```
sed -ri 's/\s{2,}/ /g' testfile
```

`-r` option allows using regexp expressions in substitutions

`-i` option allows *in-place* file modification

Comment: Thank you Roman!  I ran the command with {3,} (which wound up being the column I needed to move) and it worked like charm.